# Prevent specific user control element from being put on the copy-paste clipboard

Tags: javascript, html, clipboard

I have some data on my website that contains a "hidden" checkbox. Users on my website often copy and paste tabular data, but when they copy and paste into Excel, it often copies the checkbox along with it. How can I prevent the checkbox from being copied into the clipboard?

Please note: I *don't* want to prevent the user from copying and pasting, just I don't want a single element to not get put on the clipboard.

Here's an example of when the user currently copy and pastes into Excel (note the unwanted checkbox):

The CSS for the checkbox looks like this currently:

```css
input {
        border: 0;
        clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
        height: 1px;
        margin: -1px;
        overflow: hidden;
        padding: 0;
        position: absolute;
        width: 1px;
        user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
<tr>
  <td>Test</td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
  <td>Test 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Test</td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
  <td>Test 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Test</td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
  <td>Test 2</td>
</tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

If what's displayed in the code snippet is copy and pasted into Excel, the output looks like this:

[image: screenshot of undesired behavior]

Comment: you want to only copy the table style too but not checkboxes ?

Comment: Yes. Ideally, I'd like to do it with any element, not just checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by setting the `user-select` to `none` in your CSS file.

```css
.no-select {
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<p>Try to select me</p>
<p class='no-select'>Try to select me as well</p>
```

So your check box would look like this:

```css
        .field-name input {
            /* make the checkbox "hidden" but still focusable ('visibility: hidden'/'diplay: none' would not work here) */
            border: 0;
            clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
            height: 1px;
            margin: -1px;
            overflow: hidden;
            padding: 0;
            position: absolute;
            width: 1px;
            
            user-select: none;
        }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can still copy and paste it using Chrome. I'll update my question to include a code snippet of it.